# Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1 on Xcode 7 beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I am experiencing two different errors while trying to build/run my app. I tried doing a Clean, deleted the DerivedData (multiple times), looking at other possible solutions but nothing has worked.

Here is a link to a Dropbox where I put two screenshots of my the errors in my build log (Not a scam, I just can't post them here because StackOverflow is stupid and won't let me post images): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l7l736nl2bfwcvt/AAA-e0-8FUpvqJmAEgwgA1nAa?dl=0

Please note that "Golden Words" is the name of the project (it's a campus newspaper). I have absolutely no idea what the "Golden_Words-Swift.h" file is. I never created such a thing so I don't understand why Xcode is trying to find such a file.

Note that the "MapViewController.swift" file is a View Controller where I just use some basic MapKit features. As a beginner, I truly don't understand what "MapViewController.o" is, nor why Xcode is looking for it.

I really hope one of you can help me completely fix these errors :) My app has been plagued by errors for weeks now which has made it impossible for me to make any progress. If you want more details, ask away!

Comment: can you please show your MapViewController.swift?

Comment: I completely changed the code. It doesn't look anything like it did when I posted this question.